# CPU credit balance in RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

[image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSnZc.png)[image]I am a beginner in this AWS technology area. 
Every day I start and stop my RDS instance(db.t2.micro (MSSQL Server)) of AWS using a lambda expression. The fact that **CPU credit balance acquired and spent on a daily basis and that CPU credit balance affect CPU usage** described by AWS documentation. Daily CPU usage maximizes up 10% use. But for one day CPU credit balance was zero and CPU usage is high. I have no reason behind that's odd behaviour of rds instance. Can anyone describe me the reason? 
Please anyone can explain?

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear. Do you have a specific question? If you are asking why your CPU usage was high one day, then you have not supplied enough information for us to provide any advice.

Comment: thanks for the comment @John.i hope now the image will clarify my question.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein sir can you describe me now. I am worried about this issue.

Comment: If the database CPU usage was high (for whatever reason), it would have consumed the CPU Credits, resulting in no 'burst' capacity. However, there's no way to know why the CPU usage was high aside from observing running jobs on the database at the time. If this has a negative impact on your systems, then use a larger instance type or, preferably, a different instance family that provides consistent performance (but at a higher cost).

Comment: thanks for the comment. Can I update my credits after it fully used ??

Comment: With t2 instances, once your credits are used up, you go into degraded mode (I think it's 10% of the CPU capacity). You can upgrade to t3 instances, which work in "unlimited" modes (i.e. you pay for additional CPU power that you use once you've spent your credits)